# Add BM25 scoring in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am new-comer to Lucene. I am using Lucene in java using Lucene-3.6.0.jar. I followed the tutorial from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/. My base code is as follows:

```
public class LuceneTester {
String indexDir = "Data/Indexdir";
String dataDir = "Data/Datadir";
Indexer indexer;
Searcher searcher;

public static void test() {
    LuceneTester tester;
    try {
        tester = new LuceneTester();
        tester.createIndex();
        tester.search("malformed");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void createIndex() throws IOException {
    indexer = new Indexer(indexDir);
    int numIndexed;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    numIndexed = indexer.createIndex(dataDir, new TextFileFilter());
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    indexer.close();
    System.out.println(numIndexed + " File indexed, time taken: "
            + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
}

private void search(String searchQuery) throws IOException, ParseException {
    searcher = new Searcher(indexDir);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Term term = new Term(LuceneConstants.CONTENTS, searchQuery);
    Query query = new FuzzyQuery(term);
    System.out.println("Query: " + query.toString());
    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, Sort.RELEVANCE);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(hits.totalHits + " documents found. Time :"
            + (endTime - startTime));
    for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
        Document doc = searcher.getDocument(scoreDoc);
        System.out.println("File: " + doc.get(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH));
    }
    searcher.close();
}
```

Now, instead of default scoring technique I want to use BM25 similarity. How to do it?

Comment: Just to throw this out there, if you are just starting with Lucene, you'd probably be better off learning a more recent version, if possible.  Lucene's API has changed quite a bit since 3.6.  Lucene 3.6, I believe, didn't have a BM25 implementation out of the box.  In the current version (6.1) BM25 is actually the default similarity, and a number of other options are available.

Answer (score 4):

Lucene versions before Lucene 4.0 didn't have all information needed for BM25, i.e. document level IDF and average field lengths, so implementing BM25 in such an old version isn't directly possible (you could store the information needed externally and/or approximate them, see: http://www.slideshare.net/yuvalf/bm25-scoring-for-lucene-from-academia-to-industry for an idea).

From 4.0 Lucene includes an (at first experimental) implementation of BM25: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html

As femtoRgon suggested using Lucene 6 or newer, would give you BM25 out of the box. If this doesn't help you and you can at least use Lucene 4+ you can change the default similarity to BM25:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = ...
searcher.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity());
```